# Hive Union ALL - java nullpointer exception

Tags: nullpointerexception, hive, union-all

I have a Hive query which is something like this

```
insert into table all_data
  select a,b from t1
  union all
  select a,b from t2`
```

The above query works fine.
When I change my query to following:

```
insert into table all_data
  select a,b from t1
  union all
  select a,b from t2
  union all
  select a,b from t3
```

I get java Null-pointer errors. SO I assume that the last query has an issue.
Then I try this

```
insert into table all_data
  select a,b from t3
```

And it works.
The problem is Union All the query fails but on its own the query works.
Any pointers on how to get it working in Union All?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this.

```
insert into table all_data
select * from (
select a,b from t1
union all
select a,b from t2
union all
select a,b from t3
) u
```

Comment: Worked for me in Hive 1.1. Thanks!